# XML Data Island support/replacement solution for IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, activex

I am trying to find a fix for an issue we currently have with the web application I am developing.
We have used in the solution a lot of XML Data Islands which are now currently obsoleted by MS (see [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx)).

I have tried the following approaches:

1) use DOMParser, but unfortunately this is not support by IE 11, all the workarounds so far point me to the current approach: `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");` which is not supported any more

2) use hack to make this page as legacy document using `x-ua-compatible` in the page (see [link2](https://www.modern.ie/en-gb/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible))

3) find a library/javascript/jquery that would help me handling this issue, did not find anything more than the solutions above to cope with the situation.

And now my questions:

1. Is there any way I could cope with XML Data Islands in IE 11?
2. Is there any workaround that will work with points 1) and 2) from the above that will work on IE 11?
3. Are there any real alternatives to XML Data islands that are cross browser and don't require a full application rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach found so far was this answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986537/79379

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XML Data Block Demo</title>
<script id="purchase-order" type="application/xml">
<purchaseOrder xmlns="http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML">
  <lineItem>
    <name>Line Item 1</name>
    <price>1.25</price>
  </lineItem>
  <lineItem>
    <name>Line Item 2</name>
    <price>2.48</price>
  </lineItem>
</purchaseOrder>
</script>
<script>
function runDemo() {
  var orderSource = document.getElementById("purchase-order").textContent;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(orderSource, "application/xml");
  var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML", "lineItem");
  var firstPrice = lineItems[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML", "price")[0].textContent;
  document.body.textContent = "The purchase order contains " + lineItems.length + " line items. The price of the first line item is " + firstPrice + ".";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="runDemo()";>
Demo did not run
</body>
</html>
```