# Load XML and XSL from variables and transform in the browser

Tags: xml, xslt, client

The code snippet below is a minimal repro of an issue I am having. The aim is to transform the XML via the XSL and get the result into a variable.

Error occurs at the commented line. What am I doing wrong?

The bigger picture is that I want to be able to have the URL of an XML file, and the URL of an XSL file, both in the browser, and to transform the XML with the XSL. I have all the file-loading from server plumbing working, but I get this error and can't find an understandable answer in Google. XML transformation at the client appears to have had little focus since around 2014 so I wonder if there is either a more modern technique or plugin.

I will happily accept a plain JS or a jquery answer, or a plugin.

I know that this minimal example is not cross-browser (no solution for IE flavors) but I should say that I do need a cross-browser solution as the final answer.

Finally, I know you can transform at the server, that's not in the spec.

Here is the error from the console, and the catch.

> err=TypeError: Failed to execute 'importStylesheet' on
>   'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>
> error: {   "message":
>   "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'transformToFragment' on
>   'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.",   "filename":
>   "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 26,   "colno": 32 }

Here is the code that causes the error.

```js
var xsltProcessor, resultDocument, xml, xsl;

var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><cd><title>Empire Burlesque</title></cd></catalog>';
var xsl = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/">  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  <table border="1">    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>    </tr>    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">    <tr>      <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>    </tr>    </xsl:for-each>  </table></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>'


xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
try {
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);  // < error here !
} catch (error) {
  console.log('err=' + error);
}
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);

console.log(resultDocument);
```

Comment: If you say you have "The bigger picture is that I want to be able to have the URL of an XML file, and the URL of an XSL file, both in the browser, and to transform the XML with the XSL" then I don't understand why you show use a snippet with the XML or XSLT as Javascript strings. If you have URLs and load them with XMLHttpRequest then it has a `responseXML` of type XML DOM document you can then use for `importStylesheet` respectively as the first argument to `transformToFragment`.

Comment: If you want to load the XSLT and XML from the same server as the HTML with the Javascript comes from then see https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/arcor-archive/2016/test2016081501.html for an example that directly uses the `responseXML` of XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Nice example @MartinHonnen - like the promise.all / load process for the xml & xsl files. I'd urge readers to have a look at the style. I may well borrow some of that. I have the load working already though, but thanks. Regarding your earlier comment - yes I could load them as type application/xml but that is a workaround and not a fix - let's say some of the xml is computed locally for example, as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer so am posting in case it helps anyone else in the future. The key to the solution is to use a DomParser to parse the XML and XSL from its string form into documents.

The inspiration came from this SO question [Workaround for xml data islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748571/workaround-for-xml-data-islands)
 which led to this [MDN article about Using XML Data Islands in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) where they are explaining a workaround and they do something similar to load HTML5 'data blocks'.

NOTE: If you look in your dev console you may well see a lot of errors related to DOM exceptions and cross-origin. Looks like this code sits uncomfortably with the SO snippet machine, but if you cut & paste into your own html as a script block it runs nicely, producing a pleasing '#document-fragment' in the console.

```js
var xsltProcessor, resultDocument, xml, xsl;

var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><cd><title>Empire Burlesque</title></cd></catalog>';
var xsl = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/">    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">      <xsl:value-of select="title" />    </xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';

// Secret sauce start. 
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xsl_doc = parser.parseFromString(xsl, "application/xml");
var xml_doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
// end of secret sauce.

xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
try {
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl_doc);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('err=' + error);
}
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml_doc, document);

console.log(resultDocument);
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer this part of your question:

> XML transformation at the client appears to have had little focus
>   since around 2014 so I wonder if there is either a more modern
>   technique or plugin.

I would say it has had little focus from the browser vendors since about 2004.

But if you want something more modern, there's Saxon-JS, which is a pure Javascript implementation of XSLT 3.0. Not only does it support the 3.0 standard, it also has extensions making it interactive, so you can process user input events directly in your XSLT code. Details are at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml

Disclaimer: Saxon-JS is produced by my company, Saxonica.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Disclaimer noted.